# Can you display PDF files in a new tab within a React JS Application

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, pdf, web-frontend

I'm trying out React JS and making my first application. I wanted to make a button that would display a PDF file in a new tab, one that would appear in a new tab similar to how it would be viewed if it was in your local files. I've tried out several methods but all solutions don't really fit with my application. Is there also a way to do this completely front-end like putting the pdf files in the application files, as some solutions tell me to put it on the backend or server side.

Comment: If you have tried several things, enumerate them here and state how they didn't work.

Comment: most of them were making my own PDF Viewer but I don't believe it would fit well with my application, another was for vanilla javascript and html but I'm not sure it would apply to JSX. I'm mainly looking for something that will display based on the browser, like how I explained above.

Comment: You could import the pdf as you would a regular component, and then use an `a` tag to open it in a new window

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import react from  'react'
import file from "../../forms/f14134.pdf";


const myComponent = ()=>{
return
<div>
    <iframe
            style={{ width: "563px", height: "666px" }}
            src={file}
            type='application/pdf'
            title='title'
          />
</div>
export default myComponent
```

react will launch native browser version of the  pdf  viewer  with your object, which if  you dont have lot of you can import directly into react

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried this and it worked, I just didn't like how it took a set amount of space and not the whole window, instead `window.open(file)` did justice

Comment: i was just demonstrating the properties of the style tag, you can remove the style and it will be the whole screen :D

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with pure HTML and a little pure JS:

```
<button onclick = "showpdf('./pdfs/myfile.pdf')"></button>
<script>
function showpdf(directory){
window.open(directory);
}
</script>
```

This is if you want it in a new tab.

Comment: This one did work for HTML and Javascript but it was a little different in React, essentially I combined your answer with the one that I labelled as correct. Where you import the PDF file (`import file from 'file.pdf' and open is using `window.open(file)` file being the name of the import

Comment: No problem dude!